# Create a hyperlink from two columns, one with title and one with links, then retain only the hyperlink without losing the references

Tags: google-sheets, links, copy-paste

[Demo sheet here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K7JZtVZRYCieHg3rh5t8NERrZuAgZOrwTZ_okiP1QIo/edit?usp=sharing)

Say I have two columns, one with string literal names, and one with links (in text form)

```
A               B
Restaurant 1    http://www.link1.com
Restaurant 2    http://www.link2.com
```

I want to combine these, which I can easily do via `HYPERLINK` within another column, say C:

`=HYPERLINK(B2, A2)`

```
A               B                       C
Restaurant 1    http://www.link1.com    Combined Link+Name 1
Restaurant 2    http://www.link2.com    Combined Link+Name 2
```

My issue though, is I want to replace column A with my new combined hyperlink + name field - my ultimate goal is to combine my name and link columns into one and no longer need either.

```
A                           B
Combined Link+Name 1      http://www.link1.com
Combined Link+Name 2      http://www.link2.com
```

If I paste the combined column, or delete the existing columns, it results in removing at least one of the references in the link, resulting in either a `REF` error or the loss of the either the text or the link.  In most cases like this, I could just paste values, but pasting values loses the link, which I need to keep.  Is anyone aware of a way around this?

Comment: For anyone who might have already looked at the question, I added a link to a demo sheet.

Comment: Just hide/lock/protect/move col `A` and `B` ?

Comment: Wish I could do that, but I need it not to be pulled into something downstream.

Comment: If your downstream code only pulls data from Col `A`, perhaps create the combined link+name 1 column as an inserted column left of `A` (`=HYPERLINK(C2, B2)`) rather than col `C`

Comment: Welcome. Refer [Custom Google Spreadsheet Function Returning a Hyperlink or an Existing Formula](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10754269/1330560) and the reference to the [Google Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36757972). There are a range of workarounds and alternatives, though no promises whether any will suit you.

Comment: The 'standard way' to do these kinds of things is to put the formulas into a new column, then copy that column and **paste special** it into the first column **as values**. Then delete the columns you no longer need.

Comment: Was thinking this is the same problem I'm having, but it isn't. I added my links manually, so they don't exist as standalone data and I'm having trouble recovering them. Would have to parse the Combined link + text to get the URLs and it isn't worth the effort.

Comment: I think what you're trying to do isn't supported.
You can either use the Hyperlink function or add Links manually, one at a time. Although Sheets does support multiple links in a single cell, it does not do so with formulas, =Concat("X ", HYPERLINK(D3,C3)).

Comment: I also tried copying and pasting to OpenOffice, but couldn't get it to work.

Does anyone know if Excel supports this? I assume they do...

Answer (score 1):

`setFormula` is not available within a custom function.

One of the workarounds suggested ([by Google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36757972)) is to use onEdit(e) instead of a custom function. Unbelievably, they don't regard this workaround as "crude"!

Anyway, this is a working example of some onEdit code to get a taste for things. Presumably you could use this, then cut/paste the results to your desired location. The sky is the limit ;-)

**How to use:**

- Copy the code into the Script Editor. In order to turn the function "Off" and "On", change the function name before and after you use it.
- Enter any character in any cell to the right of the Column C on the row containing the relevant title/url.
- The character will be deleted and a static `HYPERLINK` will be inserted in its place.

---

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "Sheet1";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the range is "+e.range.getA1Notation())

  // get the sheet details
  var thissheet = e.range.getSheet().getName();

  // make sure that you're on the correct sheet
  if (thissheet != sheetname ){
    // wrong sheet; do nothing
    Logger.log("DEBUG: wrong sheet; do nothing");
  }
  else{
    // this sheet = sheetname - proceed
    Logger.log("DEBUG: this sheet("+thissheet+") = sheetname("+sheetname+") - proceed");

    // get the row
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the row is "+row)

    // use the row to get the title and url
    var title = sheet.getRange(row,1).getValue();
    var url = sheet.getRange(row,2).getValue();
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the title is "+title+", and the url is "+url)

    // setFormula in the range using the url and title from Columns A and B of the same row
    e.range.setFormula("=HYPERLINK(\""+url+"\", \""+title+"\")");
  } 
}
```

Comment: Amazing that such a common use case requires a coded solution. 
This is why I have a job (UX).